# meteor can't find module SyncedCron

Tags: angular, meteor, angular2-meteor

I have run the command:

> meteor add percolate:synced-cron

after I add to my server/main.ts

```
SyncedCron.add({
    name: 'Crunch some important numbers for the marketing department',
    schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every 0.5 minutes');
  },
job: function() {
    return 1;
  }
});
SyncedCron.start();
```

When I start the server, it is saying

> Cannot find name 'SyncedCron'

I have tried to import "synced-cron" also doesn't work.
My meteor version Meteor 1.4.2.3
Can anyone please help?

Comment: is it wrapped in a Meteor.startup() block?

Comment: are you using angular 2 meteor. this can be typescript error

Comment: Did you import the meteor package ?

Comment: Hi. Zim. yes, it is inside my Meteor.startup()

Comment: Hi. Pankaj. Yes i did import it with this line
import {SyncedCron} from 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron';

Comment: hi. Amit. yes. i am using angular 2 meteor, I am new to it.

Comment: @shiCheng did my solution worked ?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem first of all you need to import this line

```
import {SyncedCron} from 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron';
```

after importing this line you will face another error `Cannot find module 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron`
This error comes because we don't have any typescript definition for `percolate:synced-cron` package in our typings.d.ts file. So to remove this error you have to create your own typescript definition for percolate:synced-cron. so just add these line into your typings.d.ts file or in @typings folder meteor definition.

```
declare module "meteor/percolate:synced-cron"{
  export module SyncedCron { 
    function add ({ name: string, schedule:(parser: any): any, job:(): any })
    function start(): any {}
  }
}
```

now you will not get any error related to percolate: synced-cron.

Answer (score 0):

Amit.

Sorry for late reply.

i have pasted your code into my typings.d.ts, my i am still getting server/main.ts (13, 3): Cannot find name 'SyncedCron', below is my typings.d.ts file.

```
/// <reference types="zone.js" />
/// <reference types="meteor-typings" />
/// <reference types="@types/underscore" />
/// <reference types="@types/node" />

declare module '*.html' {
  const template: string;
  export default template;
}

declare module '*.scss' {
  const style: string;
  export default style;
}

declare module '*.less' {
  const style: string;
  export default style;
}

declare module '*.css' {
  const style: string;
  export default style;
}

declare module '*.sass' {
  const style: string;
  export default style;
}

declare module 'meteor/tmeasday:publish-counts' {
  import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

  interface CountsObject {
    get(publicationName: string): number;
    publish(context: any, publicationName: string, cursor: Mongo.Cursor, options: any): number;
  }

  export const Counts: CountsObject;
}

declare module 'meteor/accounts-base' {
  module Accounts {
    function requestPhoneVerification(phoneNumber: string, callback?: Function): void;
    function verifyPhone(phoneNumber: string, code: string, callback?: Function): void;
  }
}

declare module "meteor/percolate:synced-cron"{
  export module SyncedCron { 
    function add ({ name: string, schedule:(parser: any): any, job:(): any })
    function start(): any {}
  }
}
```

Comment: have you included import {SyncedCron} from 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron'; in your main.ts file ??. i have used this package in my project and its working perfectly for me not getting any error and you are getting SyncedCron error not percolate:syned-cron not found. so check how you have imported SyncedCron. and if its possible add plnkr of your code.

Comment: and one more thing. your SyncedCron code should be inside Meteor.startup() on server side

Answer (score -1):

is syched-cron realy needed to import on your server.js?
can you show your server/main.ts?

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: cannt comment except my post, i am new

Answer (score -1):

here is the code

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {SyncedCron} from 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  SyncedCron.add({
    name: 'Crunch some important numbers for the marketing department',
    schedule: function(parser) {
      // parser is a later.parse object
      return parser.text('every 0.25 minutes');
    },
    job: function() {
      return console.log(1234);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: sorry for late reply.  it looks like you have solved some part of this problem yourself. but if you include only import {SyncedCron} from 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron'; then you will face on more error "Cannot find module 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron' ". i have added complete solution . you can check.

Comment: This should be added to the original post. Please edit the original post.